# React-router. How to entirely change url in Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am on page with URL: `http://localhost:3000/courses/32` and from this place I want to redirect my page by `Link` to this URL: `http://localhost:3000/categories`.

Comment: can you pls share more details related to routes.

Comment: Hi,you can use useHistory hook for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a small example here https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-wood-ug9oc, you'll need to have setup your router first, below you can find example that should do the trick using `Link` and another with `withRouter`:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Link,
  Route,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

const Category = () => {
  return <div>Category</div>;
};

const CategoryWithRouter = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <div
    onClick={() => {
      history.push("/category");
    }}
  >
    Category withRouter
  </div>
));

const Home = () => {
  // Link case
  // withRouter case as well
  return (
    <div>
      Home
      <Link to="/category">Category</Link>
      <CategoryWithRouter />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={"/category"} component={Category} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```